# Firebase Realtime Database Rules not Working

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a `Users` collection which contains documents. Each document has a unique ID (push ids) generated automatically and a `UID` field which has the `Auth.UID` value of user. I'm trying to write a rule that allow user to read and write to document only if `UID` value matches with the `Auth.uid` value. But for some reasons all permissions are being denied. Please guide whats wrong with my code
**Realtime Database**

```json
{
  "Users": {
        "-MTvNT3Cw7JAKaMbfFuv": {
          "Email": "*****@gmail.com",
          "UID": "9Sv14dBARRTS9jsbE3j1uh0XytA2",
        },
        "-MTxOpssHRPWUCk474CZ": {
          "Email": "*****@gmail.com",
          "UID": "FAcKFSDuGOg7TdqZaInk9PDIlou1",
        }
    }
}
```

**Security Rules**

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$userDocId": {
        ".read": "auth !== null && data.child('UID').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "auth !== null && data.child('UID').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Rules Playground Logs**

> Line 5 (/Users/MTvNT3Cw7JAKaMbfFuv) read: "auth !== null && data.child('UID').val() === auth.uid"

Comment: Please edit your question to show the minimal code with which you can reproduce the error message. In that code, make sure to validate that it meets the requirements of your rules, i.e. check if there is a current user - and log their UID. Include that code and its output in your question, so that we can compare it to your rules too.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 0):

In my simulated rules I forget to add `-` at the start of Doc ID `/Users/MTvNT3Cw7JAKaMbfFuv` should be `/Users/-MTvNT3Cw7JAKaMbfFuv`